# Not able to get the _ID from an item of a listview populated from a database in android

Tags: android, database, listview

I am working on a notepad application in android. I have a SherlockListActivity, and I populate it's ListView with the information from a database. I put a listener for a longclick in order to show the ActionMode for the Actionbar. Up until here, all is well. The problem is when I click on the delete option, it shows me an AlertDialog which asks me if I am sure, and when I click Yes, it should delete it from the database, but instead, the app freezes and closes. I already found 3 answers on this website, apparently others have this problem, I tried to do the same as them, but no success. Could anyone tell me how I should proceed please? Here is my code:

```
public class Scratchpad extends SherlockListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int EDIT_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;

    private ScratchHelper mDbHelper;

    protected Object mActionMode;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scratch_list);
        mDbHelper = new ScratchHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData(); //populates the ListView with info from my DB
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
              }

              // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
              mActionMode = Scratchpad.this
                  .startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
              view.setSelected(true);
              return true;
            }
          });
    }







    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
          // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
          MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
          // Assumes that you have "contexual.xml" menu resources
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionmenu_main_longclick, menu);
          return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after
        // onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
          return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, final MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.menu_long_delete:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Scratchpad.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.confirm_delete);
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id); //THERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!!!!
                fillData();
                }
            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
            // Action picked, so close the CAB
            mode.finish();
            return true;

          case R.id.menu_long_edit:
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.scratch_modified, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              // Action picked, so close the CAB
              mode.finish();
              return true;


          default:
            return false;
          }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
          mActionMode = null;
          selectedItem = -1;
        }
      };
```

The problem is at the line where I commented "HERE IS THE PROBLEM".

Answer (score 0):

There is no `_ID` in an SQLite database, if you want the id you have to use the hidden `rowid` column.

Comment: No! I mean that I want to get the id representing my row. My table consists of _ID, TITLE, CONTENT, DATE. These are my collumns. I want to get the _ID representing the listview item that I just longclicked, because my function deletenote takes the id of the note as argument

Comment: `mListView.getPosition()`?
If you want the _ID, create a custom listview item with a hidden `TextView`, where you write the _ID in and now you can read it in the `OnClickMethod`

Answer (score 0):

for detail of you database, you can user sql manager to open database file, it same with sql manager studio of sql server....
to get database file you can user file explorer of DDMS